# predicting new non-standardized data with classifier trained on standardized data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have some data with say, `L` features. I have standardized them using `StandardScaler()` by doing a `fit_transform` on X_train. Now while predicting, i did `clf.predict(scaler.transform(X_test))`. So far so good... now if I want to pickle the model for later reuse, how would I go about predicting on the new data in future with this saved model ? the new (future) data will not be standardized and I didn't pickle the `scaler`.

Is there anything else that I have to do before pickling the model the way I am doing it right now (to be able to predict on non-standardized data)?

reddit post: `https://redd.it/4iekc9`

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you should use a pipeline. The first stage there is scaling, and the second one is your model. Then you can pickle the whole pipeline and have fun with your new data.

Comment: Nice idea... :) But in general, do you have any idea what're the best practices to follow ? Or how it is done in real world sense ?